# How can I create a new categorical variable with 3 levels from 2 binary variables?

Tags: r

```
EC <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), past_smoking=c("1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0"),current_smoking=c("0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0"))

EC

  id past_smoking current_smoking
1  1            1               0
2  2            0               1
3  3            0               1
4  4            0               1
5  5            1               0
6  6            0               1
7  7            0               1
8  8            0               1
9  9            0               0
```

to a new categorical variable with 3 levels (0=no_smoking, 1=past_smoking , 2=current_smoking?)
thank you for any help
I am quite new in R progamming

Answer (score 2):

We could use `case_when` to categorize to new categories i.e. when 'past_smoking' is 1 return 1, when current_smoking is 1, return 2 or else as '0'

```
library(dplyr)
EC %>%
   mutate(categ = case_when(past_smoking =='1' ~ '1',
         current_smoking == '1' ~ '2', TRUE ~ '0'))
```

---

Or as @user20650 mentioned

```
EC %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(categ = current_smoking + !past_smoking)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# your data
EC <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), past_smoking=c("1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0"),current_smoking=c("0","1","1","1","0","1","1","1","0"))

# create new column
EC_new <- EC %>% 
  mutate(newvar=case_when(past_smoking==0 & current_smoking==0 ~ 0,
                          past_smoking==1 ~ 1,
                          current_smoking==1 ~ 2))

# make a factor variable
EC_new$newvar <- factor(EC_new$newvar, levels = c(0,1,2),
         labels = c("no_smoking", "past_smoking", "current_smoking"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
transform(
  type.convert(EC, as.is = TRUE),
  newvar = past_smoking + 2 * current_smoking
)
```

which gives

```
  id past_smoking current_smoking new
1  1            1               0   1
2  2            0               1   2
3  3            0               1   2
4  4            0               1   2
5  5            1               0   1
6  6            0               1   2
7  7            0               1   2
8  8            0               1   2
9  9            0               0   0
```